# Correct translation settings for simple setup

Tags: i18n-l10n

In D9, I am trying to set up simple translation but am having 2 issues.
The site is English with Spanish as the alternate language.
We're using the Dropdown Language selector.
The content types and appropriate fields are enabled for translation.
I've seen so many recommendations for the order to put the detection options in, I'm not sure which would be correct. I simply want if the user clicks ES on the switcher, that the Spanish page (which DOES come up) use the Spanish alias configured in the page translation, with a language prefix, eg

/caribbean becomes /es/caribe

but instead, I receive
/caribbean?language=es

although when EDITING the content, the edit url has the language prefix.

The second problem is that when changing the page's menu link in the Spanish translation, the result is that it appears in Spanish regardless which language is selected.

Comment: If you are trying to setup a simple translation then keep the default language detection setup. It's clear you have enabled more than one language detection method. For what reason?

Comment: I was trying different combinations. That is the most recent. I notice it works fine on a vanilla install with just url selected and up top. I think I need to toss the dropdown language selector contrib. It forces the setting you see enabled and grayed out.